Azure devops build fails when using feed
In our solution, we have couple of projects that use MSBuild.SDK.SystemWeb and Azure Devops build works fine when using nuget.org as package provider.
We have introduced our local feed, enabled upstream sources and I have ran nuget restore in local (to populate feed with all packages we use). Now, our build pipeline fails on Nuget restore step with following error:
error : Could not resolve SDK "MSBuild.SDK.SystemWeb". Exactly one of the probing messages below indicates why we could not resolve the SDK. Investigate and resolve that message to correctly specify the SDK. 
error :   C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\8.0.202\Sdks\MSBuild.SDK.SystemWeb\Sdk not found. Check that a recent enough .NET SDK is installed and/or increase the version specified in global.json. 
error :   Unable to find package MSBuild.SDK.SystemWeb. No packages exist with this id in source(s): myfeed-packages NuGet.CommandLine.ExitCodeException: Exception of type 'NuGet.CommandLine.ExitCodeException' was thrown. 
error :   MSB4276: The default SDK resolver failed to resolve SDK "MSBuild.SDK.SystemWeb" because directory "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\MSBuild\Sdks\MSBuild.SDK.SystemWeb\Sdk" did not exist. 
warning : Unable to load the service index for source https://redacted/packages/nuget/v3/index.json. 
error MSB4236: The SDK 'MSBuild.SDK.SystemWeb' specified could not be found.

This package definitely exist in the feed, version matches the one we provided in global.json so I don't know what else could be the problem.
EDIT
My build pipeline looks like this:
trigger:
  paths:
    include:
    - main
name: 2.0.$(BuildID)
resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: self
    type: git
    ref: main
jobs:
- job: Phase_1
  displayName: Agent phase
  timeoutInMinutes: 180
  cancelTimeoutInMinutes: 1
  pool:
    vmImage: windows-2022
  steps:
  - checkout: self                       
  - task: UseDotNet@2
    inputs:
      packageType: 'sdk'
      useGlobalJson: true
      workingDirectory: '$(system.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
  - task: NuGetCommand@2
    inputs:
      command: 'restore'
      restoreSolution: '**/xxx.sln'
      feedsToUse: 'config'
      nugetConfigPath: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/nuget.config'


We have set msbuild.sdk.systemweb project in global.json.
We have added our feed into nuget.config file
Feed is allowed to connect upstream and download nuget packages. We have already populated feed by doing nuget restore from localhost.


It would help to see the build, specially how you configured the service connection for the nuget feed.

I tried to test the issue with the sample project in the MSBuild SDK. Then I found I got the same error message when I use NuGet restore command directly in the pipeline.
According to How can I use these SDKs?, I added a global.json in the project.
{
  "msbuild-sdks": {
    "MSBuild.SDK.SystemWeb" : "4.0.88"
  }
}

This time the NuGet restore task is successful.
steps:
- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    command: 'restore'
    restoreSolution: '**/*.csproj'
    feedsToUse: 'select'
    vstsFeed: 'my feed'
    includeNuGetOrg: false


Hm, I have added the following code snippet:

task: UseDotNet@2
inputs:
packageType: 'sdk'
useGlobalJson: true
workingDirectory: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)'

task: NuGetCommand@2
inputs:
command: 'restore'
restoreSolution: '**/xxx.sln'
feedsToUse: 'config'
nugetConfigPath: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/nuget.config'



But I am still getting the same error :/

Hi, I tested again with the sample project in the MSBuild SDK and found that the NuGet restore is successful after adding the global.json. The UseDotNet@2 is not necessary. I am not sure why it is still failed in your pipeline. Did you have version specified in the project or global.json?  As you mentioned your pipeline failed after you changed to the local feed, and it worked when using nuget.org as package provider, maybe the issue is related to the nuget.config.

You can run NuGet restore in local, but it failed in the hosted agent. Will there is any connection issue between your local feed and the hosted agent? Or you can try to run the pipeline in a self-hosted agent where you run NuGet restore locally to see if it works.

Hi, yes, I did exact same thing like you, and locally my nuget.config is fine (packages are downloaded to feed when I run nuget restore). I tried using both nuget.config and hardcoding feed id in pipeline, but it makes no difference.

Hi , glad to hear that you found the issue is that your build agents have some permission issues. This can answer why you can run NuGet restore in local, but it failed in the hosted agent.

I expected that build agent permission would either be auto provisioned for internal feed (or at least clearly indicated that we have to do this ourselves).
Anyway, thank you for your help!

Hi @BojanNedeljkovic, just wonder which local feed you are using. Is it azure artifact? Is the permission issue related to the Pipelines permissions of the feed?

Correct, I had to add our build service to feed permissions in Azure Artefacts.

Thanks for your confirmation. Could you please update this information in your answer to make it clear? So that it may help others who have the same issue in the future.

It turns out our build agents had permission issues.
I've connected our feed as an external service using PAT token and I was able to restore and build solution.
After that, I went back to the Azure Devops Artifacts feed and realized that Project Collection build service has not been granted permission to read from it.
After I granted it reader rights, build agent was able to get nuget pacakges from our internal feed.
Resolution steps:
Artifacts -> choose package feed -> click settings icon it top right corner -> select permissions tab -> add user/groups -> search for your build service and grant it Feed reader permissions.
